# Provide ServerSideEncryption to download a file from AWS S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

I have to export data from redshift to local path which SHOULD be done using PostgresOperator in Airflow. So performing this in 2 steps.

Step1: Executed unload command which exports data to S3 bucket which is AES256 Encrypted.

Step2: I'm download data from this s3 bucket to local path. Since the data is AES256 encrypted I don't know how to download by providing "ServerSideEncryption"

I'm downloading file using the method below.

`s3_client.download_file(Bucket=bucket, Key=s3_key,Filename=local_path, ExtraArgs={'ServerSideEncryption':'AES256'})`

And it throws an error saying invalid key "ServerSideEncryption" and the ExtraArgs keys should be in `['VersionId', 'SSECustomerAlgorithm', 'SSECustomerKey', 'SSECustomerKeyMD5', 'RequestPayer']`.

If I don't provide the ServerSideEncryption, IT `botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (404) when calling the HeadObject operation: Not Found`